# Ajax and PHP : SELECT query database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I have an UI in which the user can add objects (stored as JSON in my database). So, when the user is clicking on a button, it calls the ajax wich calls my php to get the desired JSON code.

The problem is that my ajax returns me "success" but with no JSON code. I don't know where the problem is located.

Here's my JS/AJAX:

```
 var object, objectJson;
    var objectName = $(this).attr("attr-lib");
    var objectId = $(this).attr("attr-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'scriptObject.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {objectId: objectId},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Here's my `scriptObject.php`:

```
$objectId = $_POST["objectId"];

    $query = "SELECT objectJson FROM object WHERE objectId = ' $objectId '";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result)
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            $objJSON = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $res = array("status"=>"success", "objectJson" => $objJSON['objectJson']);
        }
        else
        {
            $res = array("status"=>"error", "message" => "No records found.");
        }
    }
    else
        $res = array("status"=>"error", "message" => "Problem in fetching data.");

    echo json_encode($res);
```

[EDIT]

It answers me:

```
{"status":"error","message":"Problem in fetching data."}
```

Comment: the "data" field in the ajax call parameter object is supposed to be formatted as a JS object with key-value pairs like data:{objectId:objectId}

Comment: when / where do you execute getObjectJson()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var object, objectJson;
    var objectName = $(this).attr("attr-lib");
    var objectId = $(this).attr("attr-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'scriptObject.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: { objectId: objectId },
        success: function(response) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(response);
            if(json.status == 'error')
                console.log(json.message);
            else if(json.status == 'success')
                console.log(json.objectJson);
        }
    });
</script>
```

and in `scriptObject.php`

```
<?php 
    // your database connection goes here
    include 'config.php';

    $objectId = $_POST["objectId"];

    $query = "SELECT objectJson FROM object WHERE objectId = ' $objectId '";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result)
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            $objJSON = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $res = array("status"=>"success", "objectJson" => $objJSON['objectJson']);
        }
        else
        {
            $res = array("status"=>"error", "message" => "No records found.");
        }
    }
    else
        $res = array("status"=>"error", "message" => "Problem in fetching data.".mysql_error());

    echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

Comment: @sRcBh see updated PHP code. You were just echoing the result of `mysql_query` which is `Boolean` . It will never give you the result data..

Comment: it returns me `{"status":"error","message":"Problem in fetching data."}`

Comment: append `mysql_error()` at the end of `Problem in fetching data` You will get exact error

Comment: AND PLEASE STOP USING `mysql_*` They all are deprecated.. USE `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: also as we are using `json_encode` in PHP, we have to use `$.parseJSON(response);` in JQuery to access the response data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95540/discussion-between-suyog-and-srcbh).

Answer (score 0):

scriptObject.php

```
if(isset($_POST['objectId']))
{
    $objectId = $_POST["objectId"];
    $query = "SELECT objectJson FROM object WHERE objectId = ' $objectId '";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
        echo json_encode($result);
        die;
}
```

you are execution the php code inside a function.
how does the compiler or the interpreter know to execute a function inside your php file.

Answer (score -1):

Add `dataType` to your ajax options

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'scriptObject.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: objectId,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

then your php code

```
function getObjectJson() {
    $objectId = $_POST["objectId"];
    $query = "SELECT objectJson FROM object WHERE objectId = ' $objectId '";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```